# Multivariable Limit Proof

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I'm having a little trouble using delta and epsilon to prove the following limit :

$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$

So I hypothesize that the limit is zero, based on approaching the point (1,0) from the lines $y = 0$, $x = 1$, and $y = mx - m$. However, when I try to give a rigorous proof using delta and epsilon, I get stuck.

I set up the problem as :

if $0 < \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2} < \delta$ then $\lvert\frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2 + y^2} - 0\rvert < \epsilon$

Simple enough. But when I try to simplify the function, I can't seem to make any headway trying to manipulate it into something that I can directly relate to delta.

I basically can rewrite the function as $\frac{\lvert x-1\rvert \lvert y\rvert}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$, but I'm having trouble finding a way to draw any conclusions. I end up getting that the whole equation is less than one, but that doesn't seem to help.

Any insight will be immensely appreciated ! (BTW, this is not just a HW question, I really want to understand what's going on in this limit, simple as it may be.)

Answer (score 1):

The limit doesn't exist.

If you approach $(1,0)$ along the line $y=0$, the limit is $0$.

If you approach $(1,0)$ along the line $y=x-1$, the limit is ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

To see it more easily, note that
$$\frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}=\frac{y(x-1)}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$
hence, replacing $x-1$ by $u$ and $y$ by $v$, the limit can be recast as
$$\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)}\frac{uv}{u^2+v^2}$$
and then, approaching $(0,0)$ along the lines $u=0$ and $u=v$, you get different limits.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the easiest one to overlook  . . . boy do I feel stupid !

Comment: Anyone can make an algebraic error. In your case, by approaching $(1,0)$ along the general line $y=mx-m$, and leaving $m$ unknown, the simplification should have given you the limit
$$\frac{m}{1+m^2}$$
which is zero only for $m=0$.